# SQLite database with Qt fails for Release executable

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

I have this code in both the debug buid (loaded in Qt Creator) and the release build. The database seems to open without issues when using Qt Creator but fails when running the release executable file. I already copied some missing .dll files from the Qt bin folder to the release folder to get the application to load without 'missing .dll' errors, but seems like there may be some other pre-requisites I'm missing for QSql?

```
#ifndef LOGIN_H
#define LOGIN_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QFileInfo>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class login; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class login : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QSqlDatabase EPMS_db;

    void connClose()
    {
        EPMS_db.close();
        EPMS_db.removeDatabase(QSqlDatabase::defaultConnection);
    }
    bool connOpen()
    {
        EPMS_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
        EPMS_db.setDatabaseName("C:/SQLite/EPMS_1.db");

        if (!EPMS_db.open()) {
            qDebug()<<("Database failed to connect");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            qDebug()<<("Database connected successfully");
            return true;
        }
    }

public:
    login(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~login();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::login *ui;
};
#endif // LOGIN_H
```

Comment: How does your **login.cpp** look?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Copied the plugins/sqldrivers folder to the same folder containing the release executable program.